# How to filter object array based on various values within a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Given the following array of objects:

```
let list = [
    {id: 100, desc: 'Apple'},
    {id: 555, desc: 'Banana'},
    {id: 110, desc: 'Orange'},
    {id: 120, desc: 'Strawberry'}
]
```

and the following:

```
let myObj = {
    "res": {
        "myId": 555,
        "allIds": [
            {
                "subId": 100
            },
            {
                "subId": 120
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to filter the `list` array above so that it doesn't include the `myId` value and any of the `subId` values within the `allIds` array.

So based on this requirement after filtering, I expect to only see the following remaining value within the `list` array, i.e.:

```
let list = [
    {id: 110, desc: 'Orange'}
]
```

as `id: 110` doesn't equal `myId` and doesn't exist within the `allIds` array.

I tried the following which works for just `myId`:

```
let filteredArr = {list.filter((el) => el.id !== myObj.res.myId)}
```

but unsure how to also exclude/filter the `subId's` within the `allIds` array as well?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - correct. Just changed it to `myObj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried the following which works for just `myId`:
>
> ```
> let filteredArr = {list.filter((el) => el.id !== myObj.res.myId)}
> ```
>
> but unsure how to also exclude/filter the `subId`'s within the `allIds` array as well?

First, those `{...}` around `list.filter(...)` don't belong there. The `{` after a `=` starts an object initializer, but that's not valid content for an object initializer.

Use `&&` ("and") and then `myObj.res.allIds.every` to see if the `subId` of every element in `myObj.res.allIds` is **not** a match for `el.id`:

```
let filteredArr = list.filter(
    (el) => el.id !== myObj.res.myId && myObj.res.allIds.every(({ subId }) => subId !== el.id)
);
```

Live Example:

```js
let list = [
    { id: 100, desc: "Apple" },
    { id: 555, desc: "Banana" },
    { id: 110, desc: "Orange" },
    { id: 120, desc: "Strawberry" },
];

let myObj = {
    res: {
        myId: 555,
        allIds: [
            {
                subId: 100,
            },
            {
                subId: 120,
            },
        ],
    },
};

let filteredArr = list.filter(
    (el) => el.id !== myObj.res.myId && myObj.res.allIds.every(({ subId }) => subId !== el.id)
);
console.log(filteredArr);
```

That's assuming that `myObj.res.allIds` is fairly short, so it's okay to re-traverse it for (nearly) every element of `list`. If it's not short, you might want to create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) containing all of the disallowed `id` valuse (`myObj.res.myId` and the `subId` values) first, since lookup time for the `has` method of a `Set` is guaranteed to be sublinear (whereas [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) will be linear):

```
const disallowed = new Set([
    myObj.res.myId,
    ...myObj.res.allIds.map(({subId}) => subId),
]);
let filteredArr = list.filter((el) => !disallowed.has(el.id));
```

Live Example:

```js
let list = [
    { id: 100, desc: "Apple" },
    { id: 555, desc: "Banana" },
    { id: 110, desc: "Orange" },
    { id: 120, desc: "Strawberry" },
];

let myObj = {
    res: {
        myId: 555,
        allIds: [
            {
                subId: 100,
            },
            {
                subId: 120,
            },
        ],
    },
};

const disallowed = new Set([
    myObj.res.myId,
    ...myObj.res.allIds.map(({subId}) => subId),
]);
let filteredArr = list.filter((el) => !disallowed.has(el.id));
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to collate a list of ids that you want to filter out of your `myObj` object and simply filter the list. Something like this...

```js
const blackList = [ myObj.res.myId, ...myObj.res.allIds.map(o => o.subId) ]
const filteredArr = list.filter(o => !blackList.includes(o.id))

console.log(filteredArr)
```